# Matching multi-time in string

Tags: regex

I'm new to regex and need practice some test
I have following string:

```
zwr ^test1\0asdnasndzwr ^test2\0asdnk\0
```

I need to grab : `zwr ^test\0` and `zwr ^test2\0`

I'm trying using following pattern but it match whole of string

```
^zwr.*\\0$
```

https://regex101.com/r/eO6zD9/1

Please help me correct it 
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this should do the trick:

```
zwr\s*\^test\d*\\0
```

https://regex101.com/r/lT6iD5/3

You were using `^` and `$` which means the entire string can only contain the matching text, not allowing for repetitions, so I removed that.  You also had `.*` which will greedily match everything after the first `zwr`.

I made the pattern more explicit in matching the target strings, but with flexibility around what digit.

Answer (score 1):

```
zwr.*?\\0
```

first remove `^` and `$` if you global match

second use a non-greedy match `.*?`

by the way,your regex101's link have an empty line